# Change all spaces to underscores for all tables and fields without losing data

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-update

I am learning SQL Server 2008 r2 and have created a DB, but the naming convention is flawed.

1. How can I change all spaces to underscores for all tables and fields without losing data.
2. Must it be a stored procedure or is there a better alternative?

Any help in creating the 'code' is most appreciated!

Comment: Indexes, triggers, constraints, ...?  Application code?

Comment: What is the flaw to using underscores?  Wrap all objects with brackets ([ and ]).  Using underscores makes using LIKE difficult since it serves as a type of wildcard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an expansion on the accurate answer provided by @Sonam. Keep in mind that any references to the tables will be broken after the renaming.

```
Declare @OldTableName as sysname
Declare @NewTableName as sysname
Declare TableCursor Cursor Fast_Forward For
    Select
        name
    From
        sys.tables
    Where
        name Like '% %'
    Order By
        name

Open TableCursor

Fetch Next From 
    TableCursor 
Into 
    @OldTableName

While @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
Begin
    Set @NewTableName = Replace(@OldTableName, ' ', '_')

    Print 'Renaming table:'
    Print '  Old: ' + @OldTableName
    Print '  New: ' + @NewTableName

    Exec sp_rename @OldTableName, @NewTableName

    Fetch Next From 
        TableCursor 
    Into 
        @OldTableName
End
Close TableCursor
Deallocate TableCursor
```

Answer (score 0):

In a while loop, run the following code:

```
        declare @oldtblname varchar(10)
    declare @newtblname varchar(10)
    select @oldtblname=name from sys.tables where name like '% %'
    set @newtblname=replace(@oldtblname,' ','_')

    exec sp_rename @oldtblname,@newtblname
```

The while loop count would be equal to the number of tables which have space in its name.

Comment: Thank you for your help!

@Chris H, why do underscores hinder using like?